# Library for very large append only dynamic array

Tags: bigdata

I am searching for a dynamic array library that allows `append(element)` and `get(index)`. No `insert`, `set` are `delete` required.

- The array would be so large it mostly stays on the hard disk.
- The newer elements are accessed more often than older ones.
- Every random access will followed by many sequential accesses.

These shows data from very far back can be compressed and stored.

This array should be potentially infinite in size, it is bounded only by the amount of storage on the hard disk.

The file on the hard disk can be accessed by other process too, since only 1 process will do all the writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go with Python (no language mentionned ?), [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) is a good alternative. It

- uses the compact binary [HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format#HDF5) format
- can compress numeric data efficiently using [blosc](http://www.blosc.org/)
- is perf-oriented & has a lot of [optimization tips](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/optimization.html)